# Creating a Custom reporter block in Scratch

Tags: mit-scratch

Quite simple, how do I create a hacked custom reporter block in Scratch?

I know I can make my own custom command block by editing the `.json` file, but I don't know how to create a custom reporter block. I believe that it is coming to Scratch 3.0, but I want to know how to make one by editing the `.json` file within the `.sb2` file. Because I do not know how to use javascript, I don't know, but I believe in languages like C++, you can define a function that `return`s a value, like:

`int function()
       //Function body
      return 0 //Gives the function a value of 0`

Is it possible to do something like this is scratch?

People have asked me why I want to this. Imagine the main with having to calculate the factorial of a variable x every time you required to calculate statistical probabilities! You might as well make a function that assigns the result to a variable `result` and use that, but I cold only calculate one at once.

Thanks you to anybody that can help

Comment: Could you give an example of how this would be used?

Comment: Okay, now the question describes `f [input]` but still does not show how it should be used. Would the call be `f [2]` on a line by itself? I suspect you would like to use it in expressions such as `(f[2])+(f[3])`, which requires a reporter block.

Comment: @JimK , I do not mind, but I really want to know how stating 'how it will be used will help. I want to use it in a case not possible using other scratch blocks. I had one the other day, but have forgotten it now. Give me time to think.

Answer (score 1):

[Item () of ()](https://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/Item_()_of_()_(block)) is a [Reporter block](https://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/Reporter_Block).  Custom reporter blocks are not currently possible, [not even by editing JSON](https://scratch.mit.edu/discuss/topic/129306/).

To create a custom block that takes a number as input, right-click on the block definition, edit, and add a number input.

[image: pass index]

**EDIT**:

Since custom reporter blocks are not possible, the only way is by using a variable to store the result.  Here the result is stored in `f_result`.  ([rendered](http://scratchblocks.github.io/#define%20f%20%5Binput%5D%0Aset%20(f_result)%20to%20((((input)*(input))*(input))%2B((input)*(input)))%0A%0Awhen%20GF%20clicked%0Af%20%5B2%5D%0Aset%20%5Ba%20v%5D%20to%20(f_result)%0Af%20%5B3%5D%0Aset%20%5Bb%20v%5D%20to%20(f_result)%0Aset%20%5Bc%20v%5D%20to%20((a)%20%2B%20(b))))

```
define f [input]
set (f_result) to ((((input)*(input))*(input))+((input)*(input)))

when GF clicked
f [2]
set [a v] to (f_result)
f [3]
set [b v] to (f_result)
set [c v] to ((a) + (b))
```

See also [custom block with return value](https://scratch.mit.edu/discuss/topic/103358/).

Answer (score 0):

This *shouldn't* be possible, but sort of is. If you're willing to edit the project JSON, you can (ab)use some of the built-in dropdown menus to add your own custom elements.

There are particular "input specifiers" which are used in the project JSON to specify particular inputs for your custom block. [This document contains a list of all of them.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uT1vHi6IUUaUix5y3k4p28p2No6pvLNKF_yrtrajEY4/edit#gid=0)

In columns D and E of the table linked above, you can see a large list of the menus available. There is, for instance, a "backdrop" menu, which contains each backdrop name as a dropdown option. Adding "%m.backdrop" to your custom block definition will insert the backdrop dropdown. Then you can create named backdrops to appear as input elements.